# Картинка "No Avatar", если нет аватара

Tags: php, cms, dle, css

Здравствуйте.

Делаю сайт на DLE, возникли проблемы с аватарами. То есть если юзер зашел и загрузил аватар в профиле, то в комментариях аватар отображается, но если коммент будет написан от имени гостя, то аватара нет.

Вопрос. Как сделать так, чтобы если не было аватара, ставилась картинка "No Avatar"?

Код файла comments.tpl:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="comment-form">
  <tr>
    <td width="15%" valign="top">
    <div class="foto"><img src="{foto}" /></div>
    <p>{author}</p>
    </td>
    <td width="85%" valign="top">
    <div class="gr-date"><p style="float:left;">Группа:<span style="color:#F00;">{group-name}</span></p><p style="float:right;">{date}</p></div>
    <br style="clear:both;" />
    <div>{comment}</div>
    <br style="clear:both;" />
    <div class="edit">
    [group=1,2][com-edit]<p style="font-size:11px;color:gray; text-decoration:underline; float:left;">Редактировать</p>[/com-edit]
    [com-del]<p style="font-size:11px;color:gray; text-decoration:underline; float:right; margin-left:25px;">Удалить</p>[/com-del][/group]
    [group=1,2,3][fast]<p style="font-size:11px;color:gray; text-decoration:underline; float:right; margin-left:25px;">Цитировать</p>[/fast][/group]</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заходишь в папку с шаблоном, в папку images кидаешь картинку с названием noavatar.png